# Repeatedly emptying a table, keeping the table itself

Tags: delete, truncate, snowflake

I have been using "delete from table_xyz" to delete everything in the table. Would it be better to instead use truncate? What difference does it make?

Comment: This is a very old topic, have you googled?

Comment: Yes, and the answer is a lecture and not concise. I'm just wondering what I should do in my specific situation for emptying a table repeatedly.

Comment: because there is no concise answer if you need to consider different scenarios.

Comment: @jyao I edited the title of this question to be my specific situation. I am running scripts for ETL and repeatedly need to empty a table.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Do you need transactions? Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Done...

Comment: @Colin'tHart We need it because I am feeding the database data from microservice events through a staging table, and we think that we should clear the staging table between data loads. We don't think transactions are needed. It is the Snowflake Cloud DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My short answer is:

Use `truncate` if you do not see any errors (because `truncate` cannot be used in many scenarios, such as the table is referenced or the table is in replication, but you will get error in such cases)

The advantages of `truncate` (over `delete` esp. in your repeated deletion case) are:

1. fast as it does not involve big overhead of transaction logging.
2. much smaller footprint on database log.

Hope this helps !